# Jenkins Pipeline S3Upload hangs

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, upload, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline that hangs when tries to upload to s3 a file:

```
def get_temp_credentials() {
        credentials_json = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "curl 169.254.170.2$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI -ss | python -mjson.tool").trim()
        def c = readJSON text: credentials_json
        return c
    }
    
    def AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    def AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    def AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN
    
    pipeline {
        agent none
        stages {
            stage('GetMasterCredentials') {
                agent { label 'master' }
                steps {
                    script {
                        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=get_temp_credentials()['AccessKeyId']
                        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=get_temp_credentials()['SecretAccessKey']
                        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN=get_temp_credentials()['Token']
                        echo "Master AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}"
                    }
                }
            }
            stage('BUILD') {
                agent { label 'macOS' }
                steps {
                    echo "Mac AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}"
                    sh 'mkdir -p js'
                    sh 'echo "not a artifact file" > js/build.js'
                    sh 'echo "artifact file" > js/build.min.js'
    
                    sh 'mkdir -p css'
                    sh 'echo "not a artifact file" > css/build.css'
                    sh 'echo "artifact file" > css/build.min.css'
                    withEnv([
                        "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="+"${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}",
                        "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="+"${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}",
                        "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN="+"${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN}",
                        "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-2"]) {
                        s3Upload bucket:"build-artifacts", path:'Test/js/build.min.js', file: 'js/build.min.js'
                    }
                }
            }
    
        }
    }
```

This example is able to move credentials from AWS EC2 node to an on premisse node.

The only thing is that it hangs when upload, no feedback error message just job timeout.

Comment: Where is the job running? the IP you're hitting `169.254.170.2` - is the IAM Metadata endpoint that is valid for an EC2 instance (some other AWS resources) - and if you're running it in AWS/EC2 why not make use of IAM roles for auth? Also your job seems to be uploading from _wherever_ *to* S3

Comment: @SathyajithBhat,  maybe I was not clear enough, sorry.
I have a master node that is in AWS and a slave that is in on-premise server in a datacenter.
I want to upload to S3 from the on-premise server and according to the documentation s3upload uses the credentials from the master node unless we use the option "useNode". 

The things is that I do not have any feedback and the jobs just hangs uploading a file.

Comment: This is definitely authentication/network/firewall issue and you need to do isolated access testing as follows. Are you able to manually login to the `on-prem slave` ? If yes, please login to the slave host and run the `s3 upload` command and share output. Also in `macos` ,  is the value of `echo "Mac AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}"` printed correctly in the jenkins console output?

Comment: What do you mean about network error? The credentials used to do the Upload are from the Master according to the plugin documentation there are no ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID} in the slave at least explicit. 

What are now investigating is if the slave needs to have access to the master (initiate some connection)  to do the upload. If that's the case that may be the problem because master does not allow network initiated traffic from the data-center